# Gemoro says contents of a verse must be reversed to understand it. So why did the Torah write it 'backwards'?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, talmud-bavli, tosfot

The Gemoro quotes [Devorim 12 (17)](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.12.17?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en)

> לֹֽא־תוּכַ֞ל לֶאֱכֹ֣ל בִּשְׁעָרֶ֗יךָ מַעְשַׂ֤ר דְּגָֽנְךָ֙
> וְתִירֹֽשְׁךָ֣ וְיִצְהָרֶ֔ךָ וּבְכֹרֹ֥ת בְּקָרְךָ֖ וְצֹאנֶ֑ךָ
> וְכׇל־נְדָרֶ֙יךָ֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר תִּדֹּ֔ר  וְנִדְבֹתֶ֖יךָ וּתְרוּמַ֥ת
> יָדֶֽךָ׃
>
> You may not partake in your settlements of the tithes of your new
> grain or wine or oil, or of the firstlings of your herds and flocks,
> or of any of the votive offerings that you vow, or of your freewill
> offerings, or of your contributions.

The [Gemoro Makos 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.17a.12?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) quotes approvingly the deductions from this possuk by R Shimon. But R Shimon darshens the possuk reversing the order of the items mentioned in the possuk. Tosfos there explains the approval of the Gemoro for R Shimon's droshos because there is no other way to explain the possuk (and accommodate well-accepted kal vachomers).

My question is if the possuk is not given to exposition except by reversing the order of the items mentioned, why did the Torah not write the possuk in the “right” order?

Gemoro and Tosfos explain that Devorim 12 (17) can only be explained by changing the order of its items. So why did not the Torah write it in the “correct” order?